# How should a date time value in web.config be formatted for specific values?

Tags: iis, web-config, timespan

For example,

```
<clientCache cacheControlMaxAge="1.00:00:00" />
```

I know this specifies one day, but what if I want to specify 30 seconds, half a day, 4 hours, etc? Is half a day "0.50:00:00" or is it "00:12:00"? Is 30 seconds "0.00:30:00" or "0.00:00:30"?

[This MSDN link](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache) covers other options, but doesn't seem to go into details on how to format something like "in x number of minutes/hours from now," other than 1 day.

Answer (score 1):

The key concept here is that some web.config settings allow for TimeSpans, such as `cacheControlMaxAge`.

Timespans can be represented as strings in the following format:

```
[-][d.]hh:mm:ss[.fffffff]
```

And the hours (`hh`) range from "00" to "23"

So a `0.12:00:00` means half a day (12 hours), whereas a `0.5:00:00` does not.

Some additional examples

- 30 seconds - `"00:00:30"`
- Half a day - `"12:00:00"`
- 4 hours - `"04:00:00"`
- 2 days, 14, hours, 23 minutes and 5 seconds - `"2.14:23:05"`

Once I realized the setting was a TimeSpan, this article was key in clarifying:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry it took so long to post my findings, I hope this helps clarify the confusion for someone else.